# Enter character every 4(th) character in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string which is gonna be used as a serial its now in format:

XXX1XXX2XXX3XXX4

I would like it formatted as:

XXX1-XXX2-XXX3-XXX4

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  String manipulation isn't a difficult thing to research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to do this. :)

Here's yet another:

```
string s = "XXX1XXX2XXX3XXX4";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
{
    sb.Append(s[i]);

    if ((i < s.Length-1) && ((i+1) % 4) == 0)
    {
        sb.Append('-');
    }
}

s = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `string.insert`?.

> [MSDN: String.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)

I am sure you can create some logic with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str="0123567236359783590203582835";
 str.ToCharArray()
 .Aggregate("",
 (result, c) => result += ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && (result.Length+1) % 5 == 0)
                              ? "-" : "")
                             + c.ToString()
 );


// --> 0123-5672-3635-9783-5902-0358-2835
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder init = new StringBuilder("XXX1XXX2XXX3XXX4");

string insertVal = "-";

for(int i=4, i<init.length;i=i+5)
{
    init.insert(i, inserVal, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Using `Linq` as follow...

```
    var s = "XXX1XXX2XXX3XXX4xx5x";
    var list = Enumerable
        .Range(0, s.Length/4)
        .Select(i => s.Substring(i*4, 4))
        .ToList();
    var res = string.Join("-", list);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",res);
```